# Am I potentially shooting myself in the foot by making this UDP listen socket non-blocking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, select

I am building a system that sends and receives UDP packets to multiple pieces of remote hardware.

- A function `mySend` passes new information to send to a third-party API that I must use to construct the actual UDP datagram. The API locks a mutex during its work constructing and sending the datagram.
- A function `myRecv` runs in a worker thread, repeatedly asking the third-party API to poll for new data. The API invokes a UDP-receive function which runs `select` and `recvfrom` to grab any responses from the remote hardware.

The thread that listens and handles incoming packets is problematic at the moment due to the design of the API I'm using to decode those packets, which locks its own mutex around the call to the UDP-receive function. But this function performs a *blocking* `select`.

---

[image: Send sequence] [image: Receive sequence]

---

The consequence is that the mutex is almost always locked by the receive thread and, in fact, the contention is so bad that `mySend` is practically never able to obtain the lock. The result is that the base thread is effectively deadlocked.

To fix this, I'm trying to justify making the listen socket non-blocking and performing a `usleep` between `select` calls where no data was available.

[image: Alternative receive sequence]

Now, if my blocking `select` had a 3-second timeout, that's not the same as performing a non-blocking `select` every 3 seconds (in the worst case) because of the introduction of latency in looking for and consequently handling incoming packets. So the `usleep` period has to be a lot lower, say 300-500ms.

My concern is mostly in the additional system calls — this is a lot more calls to `select`, and new calls to `usleep`. At times I will expect next to no incoming data for tens of seconds or even minutes, but there will also likely be periods during which I might expect to receive perhaps 40KB over a few seconds.

My first instinct, if this were all my own software, would be to tighten up the use of mutexes such that no locking was in place around `select` at all, and then there'd be no problem. But I'd like to avoid hacking about in the 3rd-party API if I don't have to.

Simple time-based profiling is not really enough at this stage because this mechanism needs to scale really well, and I don't have the means to test at scale right now. Consequently I'm trying to gather some anecdotal evidence in order to steer my decision-making.

- Is moving to a non-blocking socket the right approach?
- Or would I be better off hacking up the third-party API (which I'd rather not do) to tighten their mutex usage?

Comment: ... why don't you just leave a thread that can sit blocking waiting for incoming data. On getting some, it quickly hands it of, and resumes it's blocking wait.

Comment: @thecoshman: because the third party API requires that the wait occurs with the mutex held. This same lock prevents sending. The question then, is whether to hack the third party code to change this strange decision to turn UDP into a uniplex protocol or to do the other thing.

Comment: Precisely. What I tried to witter on about in many paragraphs, Steve has summed up in two sentences. :)

Comment: For the record, the 3rd party API usually does comms with SPI, and their entire UDP support component was created in a non-production fashion for demos/examples only. That's why I'm having trouble with trying to get it useful for a production system in UDP mode.

Comment: So "implementing a new and better UDP support component" would be a politer way to say "hacking the third-party code"? ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes :P Also worth noting that, other than this niggly issue, as far as I can tell it's basically fit-for-purpose. That makes me even less inclined to strip it out in entirety.

Comment: Oh, man... you're shagged :(

Comment: A hacky solution (and possibly a performance problem too), but can you implement your own blocking/non-blocking/select calls on top of the third party API  by temporarily setting the socket non-blocking in your code, doing your select etc, then setting back to blocking before calling the API?  ie Only call the API recv when you know it won't block.

Comment: @Austin: Heh, yes, I could. Yikes, though!

Comment: So to boil it down the level I can think about right now... "Is it ok to listen on a non-blocking UDP port?" right?

Comment: @thecoshman: More like "just how bad is it" but yes essentially

Comment: One more option, you can't use two sockets (one for send and one for receive) with two instances of the API?

Comment: @Nim: Unfortunately not, on both counts.

Comment: IME, hacking stuff like this, (which really needs a redesign), merely increases the vacuum-pressure.

Comment: @MartinJames: As it happens, the hack (which I've written and works) fits in quite nicely and looks more like a moderately simple design correction. But it's still altering someone else's code, making future upgrades dangerous, and it does lead to a few -- shall we say -- "design inconsistencies" across similar functions.

Comment: OK, good luck with it :)

Comment: Do those send/recv calls always come in pair? Or it's possible for data to arrive totally independent of send call?

Comment: Do you have access to the underlying socket? if so, in your read thread, can you call select yourself and wait for there to be data to read before calling to the API? Then you would not need any sleeps etc. And has the advantage that you don't occupy the mutex in the api for the duration of the select.

Comment: @Adi: They will be expected to come in pairs but there's no reason to expect that this must always be the case. Anyone could craft a packet and dump it on my listen socket. But if you're thinking of binding the send and receive calls, I have scaling requirements that make this too slow. The two activities must be uncoupled.

Comment: @Nim: I think that's basically what Austin said (minus going temporarily non-blocking)? It's possible but then I have twice as many `select` calls. Plus the timeout parameters come from within the 3rd-party API so I'd be duplicating a few pieces of logic.

Comment: @Lightness Correct, that's what I had in mind. But ok, here's another idea ... would it be too hard (or even applicable) to replace the mutexes with monitors? You could introduce some application specific condition which would give other side more time to execute.

Comment: @Adi: Well the mutexes are in the 3rd party code, so if I were to go in and replace them with something else, I might as well just fix the 3rd party code in the first place. And that's what I'm [hypothetically] attempting to avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, my team and the developers of the 3<sup>rd</sup> party library have all come to the conclusion that the hack is suitable enough for deployment, and outweighs the questions posed and disadvantages associated with my potential alternative workarounds.

The real solution is, of course, to push a proper design fix into the 3<sup>rd</sup> party library; this is a way off as it would be fairly extensive and nobody really cares enough, but it does give us the answer to this question.